# Java: Why throw an exception rather than output a error message?

Tags: java, exception

For example, When we handle if(sizeOfList == 0), we throw an exception to handle it. what is the different btw these two codes below? Why not we just output a message to hand this?

```
  public DNode getFirst() throws IllegalStateException {
      if (isEmpty()) throw new IllegalStateException("List is empty");
      return header.getNext();
```

}

```
  public DNode getFirst() {
      if (isEmpty())  
         System.out.println("List is empty");
      return header.getNext();
```

}

Comment: Who's going to see the output? How will the caller know there's a problem?

Comment: How does the caller know something's gone wrong?

Comment: The caller can know it from an output. - System.out.println("List is empty"); What is the benefit to throw an exception? Thanks